# Two Python modules require each other's contents - can that work?

Tags: python, python-module

I have a Bottle webserver module with the following line:

```
from foobar.formtools import auto_process_form_insert
```

And the `foobar.formtools` module contains this line:

```
from foobar.webserver import redirect, redirect_back
```

Of course, both result in the following errors (respectively):

> ImportError: cannot import name auto_process_form_insert
>   ImportError: cannot import name redirect

Is it simply a fact that in Python two modules can't import each other and all module imports must be hierarchical in nature, or am I doing something wrong? Alternatively, is there a workaround short of placing all these nice functions in new modules?

Comment: As explained in my answer, it is possible for modules to import each other, but if you need to do that, you may want to reconsider your design.

Comment: I think this explanation much easier to understand: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642451/python-files-import-from-each-other

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python

Comment: While two modules can import each other, it can get messy in practice. I found that when some of my methods were decorated with Keras registration decorators, I would get double-registration errors unless I hid them as inner methods within another method of the class.  It seemed one of the modules was being imported twice, despite the theory discussed here.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Modules *can* import each other cyclically, but there's a catch. In the simple case, it should work by moving the `import` statements to the bottom of the file or not using the `from` syntax.

Here's why that works:

When you import a module, Python first checks `sys.modules`. If it's in there, it just imports from there. If it's not there, it tries to import it in the normal way; basically, it finds the file and runs the stuff in it.

Running a module populates the module's contents. For example, say we have this module, creatively named `example_opener`:

```
import webbrowser

def open_example():
    webbrowser.open('http://www.example.com/')
```

At the start, the module is empty. Then Python executes:

```
import webbrowser
```

After that, the module only contains `webbrowser`. Then Python executes this:

```
def open_example():
    webbrowser.open('http://www.example.com/')
```

Python creates `open_example`. Now the module contains `webbrowser` and `open_example`.

Say `webbrowser` contained this code:

```
from example_opener import open_example

def open(url):
    print url
```

Say `example_opener` is imported first. This code is executed:

```
import webbrowser
```

`webbrowser` has not yet been imported, so Python executes the contents of `webbrowser`:

```
from example_opener import open_example
```

`example_opener` *has* been imported, but not yet fully executed. Python doesn't care. Python pulls the module out of `sys.modules`. At this point, `example_opener` is still empty. It hasn't defined `open_example` yet, nor even completed importing `webbrowser`. Python can't find `open_example` in `example_opener`, so it fails.

What if we imported `open_example` from the end of `webbrowser` and `webbrowser` from the end of `example_opener`? Python would start by executing this code:

```
def open_example():
    webbrowser.open('http://www.example.com/')
```

`webbrowser` does not exist yet, but it doesn't matter until `open_example` is called. Now `example_opener` contains only `open_example`. It then executes:

```
import webbrowser
```

It has not been imported yet, so Python executes `webbrowser`. It starts:

```
def open(url):
    print url
```

It defines `open`. Then it executes:

```
from example_opener import open_example
```

`example_opener` is in `sys.modules`, so it uses that. `example_opener` contains `open_example`, so it succeeds. Python finishes importing `webbrowser`. That concludes importing `webbrowser` from `example_opener`. That's the last thing in `example_opener`, so the import of `example_opener` finishes, successful, as well.

Comment: Nice breakdown. This is usually what I have to do in django where sometimes you just have to import circularly. Import at the bottom or within the function or method scope.

Comment: @Codemonkey: I noticed you added that you can avoid using the `from ... import ...` syntax, but I already have that in my answer at the top: "In the simple case, it should work by [...] not using the `from` syntax."

Answer (score 40):

Don't do `from ... import ...`.  Just do `import ...` and reference its objects using the module name.

Comment: I don't think that will address a circular import issue though?

Comment: @jdi: It will. At the time of the import, the module will be empty, but since it's not trying to get at anything inside of it (yet), it doesn't matter.

Comment: Ah, true. Thats an approach instead of importing directly at the bottom

Comment: I'd say it's not particularly recommended to put imports at the botttom or at mixed points throughout. As a general rule of thumb.

Comment: This makes maintainability much easier too, imagine someone seeing imports on the bottom, thinking its silly to be there, moving them to the top and watching your code break.

Comment: If you try to access the second module's attributes at the module scope of the first module imported, this could have the same error. For example, say I `import foo` from inside `bar.py`. And I `import bar` from inside `foo.py`. Say `foo.py` gets processed first. `foo -> import bar -> import foo`, where the final `import foo` would reference the partially instantiated `foo` module. Now if inside bar.py, at the module scope, I did something like `bar_constant = max(100, foo.foo_constant)`, it will fail, since the `foo` that bar.py can get a handle to has not instantiated `foo_constant` yet.