# NameError: name 'test' is not defined , when trying to run a function in an imported module/script Python 3

Tags: python

I'm keeping a GUI script and a logic script separate to keep things simpler (using VSCode) and when I run the GUI script I'm calling a function in a logic script:`GUI.destroy_window()` which in turn calls a function in GUI:

```
def destroy_window():
    test.destroy()
```

However, even though I previously defined test in GUI when I ran it, I get this:

> ```
> line 43, in create_monitor
>     GUI.destroy_window()
>  line 30, in destroy_window
>     test.destroy()
> NameError: name 'test' is not defined
> ```

Note: I have imported both scripts into each other and I made test global.

Comment: can you show us the full code? where you are calling the destroy_window() function?

Comment: `def create_monitor(monitor_url, monitor_counter_arg):
    website_url = monitor_url
    url = requests.get(website_url) # Could be better if I found a way to use access title from get_content without global
    url_html = url.content
    html_parser = etree.HTMLParser()
    tree = etree.fromstring(url_html, html_parser)
    title = tree.findtext( './/title' )                                 
    copyfile('default_config.py', f'config{monitor_counter_arg}.py')
    mod = importlib.import_module(f'config{monitor_counter_arg}')
    keys = mod.keys
    GUI.destroy_window()`

Comment: You need to be careful when two modules imports each one in the other one. I can create error. I'm not sure if this your case, but it seems that is from your "note part" so look on this question to explore the idea [cyclic import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11698530/two-python-modules-require-each-others-contents-can-that-work)

Comment: create_monitor is being called as logic.create_monitor() from GUI

Comment: @lulian I'll look into that, Thanks

Comment: @Zen Koh  add all the code posted in the comment in the question's detail and indent it so it will be easier to look at it and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `test` is not known in the [scope](https://matthew-brett.github.io/teaching/global_scope.html) of the function `destroy_window`.

Try to pass the object to the function instead:

```
def destroy_window(window):
    window.destroy()

destroy_window(test)
```