# Call function from file that has already imported the current file

Tags: python

If I have the files frame.py and bindings.py both with classes Frame and Bindings respectively inside of them, I import the bindings.py file into frame.py by using `from bindings import Bindings` but how do I go about importing the frame.py file into my bindings.py file. If I use `import frame` or `from frame import Frame` I get the error `ImportError: cannot import name 'Bindings' from 'bindings'`. Is there any way around this without restructuring my code?

Comment: [Two Python modules require each other's contents - can that work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11698542/8146707)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `from bindings import Bindings` try `import bindings`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what we call circular import. Let's look at the example. We have the two files:

`frame.py`

```
from bindings import Bindings

class Frame:
    pass
```

`bindings.py`

```
class Bindings:
    pass

print("class Binding here")

from Frame import Frame
```

First thing you should know is, whenever we import a file, the code in the file we're importing is also executed at the same time. So in my example, when you run the `frame.py` file, it first executes the `bindings.py` file, where it will also find what it's looking for (i.e. class `Bindings`). And while the `bindings.py` files is being executed, the `from Frame import Frame` line will then execute the `frame.py` file, getting what it wants (i.e. class `Frame`).