# Array not appending text when called from another file

Tags: python

When I run a function in file A from file B, the function in file A doesn't work as expected.

Here's what I mean.
File A is the main file, file B is another file that handles another thing. (Think tkinter and backend)

I ran into this issue while developing some functions for GPT-3, with a tkinter interface and a backend to call the functions.

File A

```py
array = []
import fileB


def addstuff(stuff):
    array.append(stuff)
    return stuff


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(array)
```

File B

```py
import fileA
test1.addstuff("test")
print("Added stuff")
```

The output that I get in the console for the `print(array)` is just an empty list.

Comment: You got an error when on the second page?

Comment: How do you invoke your scripts ?

Comment: What do you mean by how do you invoke you scripts?

Answer (score 0):

At the outset, let's walk through the execution of your code step by step:

1. When you include `import fileA` at the beginning of `fileB`, Python starts executing `fileB` from the top.
2. The import statement (`import fileA`) tells Python to look for and execute `fileA`.
3. In `fileA`, if there's a `main` function defined, it becomes the entry point of the program. However, keep in mind that Python doesn't automatically run the `main` function when you import a module. You need to explicitly call it in your code(that you did!).
4. Inside `main` in `fileA`, if there's an empty list (array) being printed, it will indeed print an empty list because no values have been assigned to it yet.
5. Once the execution in `fileA` is complete, Python returns to `fileB`.
6. In `fileB`, after the import, there's a function call to `addstuff`, which appends the string "test" to the list defined in `fileA`.
7. Finally, any further code in `fileB` is executed as well.

Note: To avoid circular imports, ensure that you don't have a situation where `fileA` imports `fileB`, and `fileB` imports `fileA` directly or indirectly. Circular imports can lead to unexpected behavior and should be avoided.

Comment: My question here is why the array is empty. This is what I think happens when File A is ran.

array is declared, then File B is ran (cos it's imported). File B then runs the code that is not in the `if __name__ == "__main__"`, so it gets access to the function but does not print anything. It then calls a function in File A, which should append something to the array. Then, File A should get the `if __name__ == "__main__"`part, which prints the array, that should contain "test" in it. I don't understand why it doesn't.

Comment: `array is declared, then File B is ran (cos it's imported)` Python does not execute File B immediately upon import in the normal way here; rather, it handles circular imports gracefully. To understand how Python manages circular imports, you can refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11698542/22491655).