# Python: import each other

Tags: python

I know there are some question about this problem :
[Python files - import from each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642451/python-files-import-from-each-other)

But this solution doesn't work for me.

This is directory structure:

```
├── tester.py
└── utility
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── analysis.py
    └── util.py
```

**__init__.py**

```
from .analysis import *
from .util import *
```

**analysis.py**

```
import util


def funcA():
    print("a")
```

**util.py**

```
import analysis

def funcB():
    print("b")
```

But this occur,

```
ImportError: No module named 'util'
```

I want to main `__init__.py` the way I defined.

Is there any way I can fix this problem?

Comment: The error occurs in which module?

Comment: Refer to [this link for clear explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11698530/two-python-modules-require-each-others-contents-can-that-work)

Comment: Your example should provide some indication of *why* each module needs to import the other.

Comment: You can also move import statements to the end of file. [Two Python modules require each other's contents - can that work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11698530/two-python-modules-require-each-others-contents-can-that-work)

Answer (score 3):

It's a classic case of circular imports. `analysis` is importing from `util` and `util` is importing from `analysis`. Although you can resolve the problem, by importing inside a function/method such that it happens at runtime, I'd suggest improving the design of the code.

More often than not circular import error is a sign that there's a problem in your code design. In your case, either the code in `analysis` file and `util` file belongs together in a single file, or you need to store the common content of both the files in a separate `common` file and import from `common` in both the files, instead of importing from each other.