# Django Attribute Error: module 'appname' has not attribute models

Tags: python, django

I know my question probably deals with mutual/circular imports, and I did search SO before posting. The only solution I found that currently solves my problem is to move imports to the end of one of the files, just before the imported functions are actually used. But I've also read that's highly unrecommended.

A recommended solution, to just do:

in `A.py` -> `import B`

and in `B.py` -> `import A`

And then access the functions, isn't working.

So I have three apps in my Django app: "core", "notifications", and "accounts". Here are snippets from them:

core.models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import notifications.models
from z_misc import general_scripts

# Create your models here.

class BaseModel(models.Model):
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Here's how I use `Notification` in `core.models`:

```
# inspect mb for each artist
### Assume class is defined and @classmethod is intended, having some formatting pains here
@classmethod
def refresh_from_mb(cls):
    artists = cls.get_artists_with_subs()
    for artist in artists:
        added_rgs = general_scripts.refresh_artist(artist.mbid)

        for rg in added_rgs:
            new_notification = Notification(artist_id=artist.id, release_group=rg)
            new_notification.save()
```

notification.models:

```
from django.db import models
import core.models
import accounts.models

class Notification(core.models.BaseModel):
    artist_id = models.OneToOneField(core.models.Artist, related_name="artist_notifications", null=False)
    release_group = models.OneToOneField(core.models.ReleaseGroup, related_name="rg_notifications", null=False)

    def get_rg_type(self):
        return self.release_group.type
```

accounts.models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import core.models
from django.db.models import Q

# Create your models here.

class UserProfile(core.models.BaseModel):

    #TODO: add email_activated = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="user_profile")
```

As you can see, I'm following the advice not do `from` and then `import`, but to rather `import` and then use the full notation. It doesn't work. The full error traceback is:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x10fa9af28>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/bap_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/bap_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/bap_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 251, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/bap_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/bap_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/bap_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/bap_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/username/.virtualenvs/bap_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.6.1/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/username/PycharmProjects/artist_notify/core/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    import notifications.models
  File "/Users/username/PycharmProjects/artist_notify/notifications/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    import accounts.models
  File "/Users/username/PycharmProjects/artist_notify/accounts/models.py", line 8, in <module>
    class UserProfile(core.models.BaseModel):
AttributeError: module 'core' has no attribute 'models'
```

I'm not sure what can I do to solve it at this point. Except start moving import statements to the middle/end of files, which seems like a big no-no.

Please don't suggest I use `from app.models import ModelName`, because that's what I was using before until errors started coming out because of circular imports.

Comment: How do you use the models in core?

Comment: Which class does `refresh_from_mb` belong to?

Comment: @Alasdair - a `UserProfile` model which inherits from `BaseModel` which is defined in `core.models`, `UserProfile` is defined in `accounts.models`.

Comment: You could break the circular import by moving `BaseModel` out of `core` (or by moving the class with `refresh_from_mb` out of `core`.

Comment: @Alasdair gee, I messed up. `refresh_from_mb` belongs to an `Artist` model which inherits from `BaseModel` which is defined in the same `core.models`.

Comment: @Alsdair - just did what you suggested. Now I'm getting a different import error about a different model defined in core.models called ReleaseGroup, and used in a utils folder. Something is seriously messed up here.

Comment: @Alasdair - Now the problem seems to be that I'm importing a function from `core/general_scripts.py` in `core/models.py`. But in the `general_scripts.py` file I also import two models (Artist, ReleaseGroup) from `core/models.py`. I don't know how I can avoid this though!

Comment: The circular import is a hint that you have code in the wrong place. Perhaps `refresh_from_mb` doesn't really belong in your `models.py`. I don't know what's in `general_scripts` so I can't tell you how to solve it specifically.

Comment: @Alsdair: This was actually a little enlightening. So Python is "forcing" me, in its own indirect way, to use my code in the right place? because actually the function I'm importing from `general_scripts` is called `refresh_artist`, which I could've (and probably should've) written as a class method in Artist. Your comment got me in the right direction, so thank you! but I'm left wondering...

Comment: It’s more of a hint than forcing you. You could move the `from z_misc import general_scripts` inside of the `refresh_from_db` method, but when you find yourself doing that it’s an indication that you might not have the right structure.

Answer (score 6):

Circular references, and imports in particular, are something you need to avoid during your design. IOW, this is a design bug more than an implementation bug.  Your situation, simplified, is (`A -> B` indicating that `A` is imported by/into `B`, and `N` = notifications, `C` = core, and `A` = accounts):

```
N -> C
C -> N
A -> C
A -> N
```

if we draw that graphically, it's easier to see that we need to solve the circularity between `C` and `N` only:

[image]

i.e. we only need to remove one of the arrows/imports between `C` and `N`.

### Django special case

Django has a number of features that can be used to decouple circular reference graphs, like:

**use string references:** to models in foreign keys, so instead of

```
from core.models import ReleaseGroup  # this is how you should import models
class Notification(...):
    release_group = models.OneToOneField(ReleaseGroup, ..)
```

you'll do:

```
# no import of ReleaseGroup model
class Notification(...):
    release_group = models.OneToOneField('core.models.ReleaseGroup', ..)
```

Django has a few helpful features like this, e.g. you can many times traverse the relationships and avoid importing, e.g. instead of:

```
Notification.objects.filter(release_group=ReleaseGroup.objects.get(pk=1))
```

which requires an import of both `Notification` and `ReleaseGroup`, you can do:

```
Notification.objects.filter(release_group__pk=1)
```

### General case

In the general case you need to use one or more of combine, extract, move.

**combine:** this one is simple, if you combine `C` and `N` into one bigger module then you've solved the circularity (circularity within one file is perfectly fine).

**extract:** if you can find some subset of code that can be pulled out into a new module, such that this new module is either at the top or bottom of the import graph then you've solved the circularity, e.g. if you have two modules, with many models, but only two of them have a circular reference (X2 and Y2 here):

```
x.py:
class X1(Model): 
    ...
class X2(Model):
    y2 = ForeignKey(Y2)
class X3...

y.py:
class Y1(...): ..
class Y2(Model):
    x2 = ForeignKey(X1)
...
```

then the circularity can be solved by introducing a new module (x.py and y.py would import X2 and Y2 from xy.py respectively)

```
xy.py:
class X2(Model):
    y2 = ForeignKey(Y2)
class Y2(Model):
    x2 = ForeignKey(X1)
```

leaving the other models where they are. (Note: extract can be used with only one model as well -- and I think your `BaseModel` might be a candidate for extraction).

**move:** is similar in spirit to extract, you find a small piece of code that is causing the circularity and move it to another existing module so it no longer causes a circularity. In the example above, X2 could have been moved to y.py or Y2 could have been moved to x.py.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you read that advice, but it is completely wrong. A circular import is a circular import, no matter what form of the import statement you use.

The solution here is *not* to import the models at all into core. You don't seem to need them there, as you don't refer to them.

Comment: I *do* use them. These were snippets just to show the imports at the beginning of the file. In any case, I just converted back from `import x.y` to ` `from x import y`, and I get `cannot import name BaseModel`. Is my only out mid-file imports? how bad is it?

Comment: btw, this is [one instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642451/python-files-import-from-each-other) where this is advised. Not that it matters much to the problem at hand because even that doesn't work.

Comment: You need to show how you're using them. It's pretty unusual to need such a complex set of imports. Are you just using them in foreign key references? If so, see the docs on [lazy references](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey).

Comment: Thank you for the reference. Unfortunately, I also use them outside of foreign key references. I've added an example.

Comment: If those relationships were foreign keys rather than one-to-one fields, you wouldn't need the reference there either; you could just do `artist.notification_set.create(release_group=g)`. I must say, it looks like you should actually have ForeignKey fields there, anyway.

Comment: @Daneil - hmmm, that makes sense actually. Each artist can have many notifications. But each notification only can belong to one artist. The problem is - I also want to create many `NotificationJob`s for each Notification, hence the separate model..

Comment: And now I'm wondering about the differnece between foreignkeys and one-to-one relationships...

Comment: A foreignkey is a one-to-many relationship, which it seems like you want; one artist, many notifications.